# iOS7.1.2 Region Monitoring not working when Wifi is off

Tags: ios, iphone, location, monitoring, region

in iOS7.1.2 (iPhone 5s) I'm developing a App with Geofencing, the regioning works pretty well as long as Wifi is turned on.
As soon as I turn off Wifi I don´t get proper regioning enter or exit events (sometimes I get no event anymore), when the app is running in the background.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Thanks,
Andreas

Comment: My guess is that you will not be able to fix that. I would report it to apple in bug report so they may fix it later release